# What layout system does Visual Studio use?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I can't find this anywhere. So, does anyone know what layout system Visual Studio (2010) itself uses? Is it built on WPF, Windows Forms, or something else entirely? If there is an available API including all the nifty drag-and-drop panel ordering I would like very much to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that the GUI has been reimplemented in WPF for VS2010. Can't help with the API question unfortunately.